# How to run my scheduler with the php artisan serve command?

Tags: php, laravel

I have added a `schedule->call(what_i_want_to_do)` to the schedule function in the Kernel.php file.
I know I can try it by running the `php artisan schedule:run` command, but, when I start my server with the `php artisan serve` command, my scheduler doesn't work.

How to make it work ?

My kernel.php schedule

```php
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $schedule->call(function () {
        Defi::whereDate('date_vis', '=', now())->update(['vis' => 1]);
    })->everyMinute();
}
```

Comment: are we talking about local developement or production server?

Comment: You need to be running a daemonized supervisor so it can keep the process of the schedule running all the time https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queues#supervisor-configuration

Answer (score 1):

Think you also need to run `php artisan schedule:work`

https://laravel.com/docs/scheduling#running-the-scheduler-locally

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am using Laravel 7.x so I can't use this command. I could upgrade my laravel to 8.x but it is for a school project and I am at the end of it. 
Should I add a command `php artisan schedule:run` in the kernel.php file

Comment: If you don't want to upgrade, then another option might be to implement the `schedule:work` command yourself. I found an article about the implementation and it's only a few lines https://laravel-news.com/schedulework

Answer (score 0):

Use cron and then set it to run php artisan schedule:work every minute